# How can I output notification about missing form fields previously collected in an array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have checked the `$_POST` data for missing required fields and generated an array of messages. Now I want to output those in one place, into the `<div class"panel">` where the placeholder "Errors will go here" currently is. However, I have no idea how I can get it work.

How can I output all the messages in this single place?

My PHP code

```
session_start();

require_once 'libs/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'])) {
$fields = [
'name' => $_POST['name'],
'email' => $_POST['email'],
'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
'message' => $_POST['message']
];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)) {
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
    }
}
} else {
$errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
header('Location: contact.php');
?>
```

The HTML

```
<section id="main" class="container 75%">
                <header>
                    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                    <p>Submit all questions and concerns here and we will respond as soon as possable!</p>
                </header>
                <div class="box">
                <div class="panel">
                Errors will go here
                </div>
                    <form method="post" action="contactformmail.php">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" placeholder="Subject" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row uniform">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions align-center">
                                    <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

What your current PHP code does is it stores all caught errors in to the array, errors, and writing it to the $_SESSION['errors'] variable.

Since your HTML did not call this variable, you will need to add an echo out to the html code.

To do this, add the code below in the box.

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) {
echo $error, '<br>';
} ?>
```

Comment: I put that in the div box but yet i still get nothing output to that div box?

Comment: @BestThereEverWas try this again

Comment: thats still an array

Comment: i used echo $_SESSION['errors']; and it printed "Array"

Comment: @dagon okay didnt realise it was an array! my bad! try this

Comment: perhaps: `echo implode('<br>',$_SESSION['errors']);`

Comment: You should be a little bit more verbose. Explain what should be done and how it works. I would vote for rep. if this became a full qualified answer.

Comment: And since it is an array, we have to loop to print each single string of it. ;-) ( Or: `implode('<br>', $_SESSION['errors']) . '<br>'` )